# MySQL connection to a win form app in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I can't get the form design to work my project compiles perfectly, but when I try to get click my button the file say key word not supported "allowloadlocalinfile"

I copied and paste what i thought was the connection string

```
server=localhost;userid=root;database=resume;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowloadlocalinfile=False;sslmode=None
```

but i get this error

here is my interface code

```
    using System;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Resume2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;database=resume;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowloadlocalinfile=False;sslmode=None");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO fields VALUES (@ResumeF_Name,@ResumeL_Name)", 
            con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResumeF_Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResumeL_Name", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I leave out the id column because it is set to auto_increment but he other to columns in my MySQL database "resume" table "fields" are `ResumeF_Name` and `Resume_L_Name`

now it's saying the connection string is server=localhost;user id=root;database=resume but still have a popup error

Comment: What other research did you do to see what connectionString should look like. Did you try without that keywork

Comment: SqlConnection is for **Microsoft SQL Server** - you need a connection class for **mysql**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a connectionString for MySql instead of MS SQL.

Here are the main steps:

1. You have to add the nuget package "**MySql.Data**" to your project
2. Then you have to add the using `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient();` to your code
3. You can then use this `MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=resume;Uid=root;Pwd=yourPassword;");`

If you need some information about the connectionString for MySql. You can find out more information at this website: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Comment: Note 1: in order to install the nuget package is necessary that the project has "destination framework" at least ".NET. Framework 4.5.2". - Note 2: "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;" without brackets